# MBK_IN_PH command not found while working with Alliance cad 5.0

Tags: environment-variables

wanted to run commands :

```
MBK_IN_PH = ap
export MBK_IN_PH
MBK_OUT_LO = spi
export MBK_OUT_LO
```

but getting command not found

Answer (score 2):

When doing variable assignment, there can't be any unescaped spaces. The shell is interpreting `MBK_IN_PH` in the first line as a command. Instead, you code should read:

```
MBK_IN_PH=ap
export MBK_IN_PH
MBK_OUT_LO=spi
export MBK_OUT_LO
```

Or you could just shorten it to:

```
export MBK_IN_PH=ap
export MBK_OUT_LO=spi
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
MBK_IN_PH=${ap}
export MBK_IN_PH
MBK_OUT_LO=${spi}
export MBK_OUT_LO
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal just enter this in your directory:

```
 setenv MBK_IN_PH ap
```

or

```
MBK_IN_PH=ap
```

For verifying this,in the terminal enter:

```
 echo $MBK_IN_PH
```